# Python selenium get table values into List of Lists

Tags: selenium

I'm just trying to get the data from this table:
https://www.listcorp.com/asx/sectors/materials

and put all the values (the TEXT) into a list of lists.

---

I've tried so many different methods using--> xpath, getByClassName, By.tag

```
------------
rws = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td")
---------------
table = driver.find_element_by_class_name("v-datatable v-table theme--light")
--------------
findElements(By.tagName("table"))
--------------
# to identify the table rows
l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//*[@class= 'v-datatable.v- 
table.theme--light']/tbody/tr")
# to get the row count len method
print (len(l)) 
# THIS RETURNS '1' which cant be right because theres hundreds of rows
```

And nothing seems to work to get the values in an easy way to understand the manner.

---

(EDIT SOLVED)

before doing the SOLVED solution below.

First do: time.sleep(10) this will allow the page to load so that the table can actually be retrieved. then just append all the cells to a new list. YOU WILL NEED MULTIPLE LISTS to fit all the rows.

Comment: You mean you want getText of all cell in table then add them to List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you can use `find_elements_by_tag_name`

and use this code

```py
row = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
data = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

print('Rows --> {}'.format(len(row)))
print('Data --> {}'.format(len(data)))

for value in row:
    print(value.text)
```

Have proper wait to populate the data.